# System.Drawing.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType)

Tags: c#, image, rotation

I have the following code to rotate an image in C#:

```
    using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
    {
        using (var image = Image.FromStream(stream))
        {
            stream.Close();
            image.RotateFlip(rotateType);
            image.Save(path1, ImageFormat.Png);
            image.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

If the original file size was 700 KiB, the new rotated file has size of 7+ MiB.

What is wrong with this code? Any help is much appreciated.

**Update:**

I tried changing the line `image.Save(path1, ImageFormat.Png)` to `image.Save(path1)` and `image.Save(path1, image.RawFormt)` with no improvement.

Comment: thats because of the conversion your original image is probably jpg.

Comment: @terrybozzio, I already tried passing Image.RawFormat, if that's what you're pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

PNG is a bitmap file format:

- higher filesize compared to jpg

Because of this you should safe your image as jpg:

> Thus lossless PNG format is best suited for pictures still under edition - and the lossy formats, like JPEG, are best for the final distribution of photographic images, because in this case JPG files are usually smaller [...]

Source: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_file_formats#PNG)

Try safing the image in JPEG via:

```
image.Save(path, YourClass.GetImageFormat(image));
```

**Tests:**
Rotating an JPG file with this method and the size stays the same.
Rotating a 15.7MiB BMP file, the new size is ~800kiB.

To use the existing file format, use this extension method:

```
public static System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat GetImageFormat(System.Drawing.Image img)
{             
    if (img.RawFormat.Equals(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg))
        return System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg;
    if (img.RawFormat.Equals(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp))
        return System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp;
    if (img.RawFormat.Equals(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png))
        return System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png;
    if (img.RawFormat.Equals(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Emf))
        return System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Emf;
    if (img.RawFormat.Equals(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Exif))
        return System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Exif;
    if (img.RawFormat.Equals(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif))
        return System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif;
    if (img.RawFormat.Equals(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Icon))
        return System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Icon;
    if (img.RawFormat.Equals(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.MemoryBmp))
        return System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.MemoryBmp;
    if (img.RawFormat.Equals(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff))
        return System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff;
    else
        return System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Wmf;            
}
```

Source: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397512/find-image-format-using-bitmap-object-in-c-sharp)

Remember you have to look for the format before you manipulate the image. 
Otherwise the image will be recognised as `MemoryBmp`.

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (var image = Image.FromStream(stream))
            {
                stream.Close();
                var format = YourClass.GetImageFormat(image);
                image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
                image.Save(path, format);
                image.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Instead of `path.Replace(Path.GetExtension(path),".jpg")`, try `Path.ChangeExtension(path,".jpg")`.

Comment: I want to at least retain the existing format, whichever it it.

Answer (score 0):

[C# - How to change PNG quality or color depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419222/c-sharp-how-to-change-png-quality-or-color-depth/)

This guy's question looks similar to the same thing you are seeing.